# How to use git credentials in systemd service

Tags: systemd

I'm using Github as the remote repository of my project and to save my time, I've executed the command `git config --global credential.helper store` to store the password in the file `~/.git-credentials`.

So I can execute `git pull` without typing password.

Now I'm trying to create a service file `git-clone.service` as below, which executes a bash script named `pull_basic_lib.sh` containing the command `cd ~/project && git pull`:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target

[Unit]
Description=git clone basic libraries

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/me/bin/pull_basic_lib.sh
```

However, when I execute `systemctl start git-clone.service`, I get the error:

```
could not read Password for 'http://me@xxx.github.com': No such device or address
```

Well, it doesn't seem that the file `~/.git-credentials` can be imported into the service.

Is there any method to solve this problem?

Comment: Is that a system service or a user service? If it's a system service, it might be running as root, so the home directory will be `/root`, and `git` will have no idea of your `~/.git-credentials`.

Comment: @muru  You are right. Adding `User` and `Group` works.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a keypair instead. This not only can automatically authenticate you, but is also more secure than locally storing your password. See githubs guide [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) on how to link your key.

Then you’ll need to [setup your ssh config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455974/setting-up-ssh-keys-for-github) locally so that it uses that key when making a connection to `github.com`. You may also need to make sure you are using the ssh equivalent of your repository URL. You can check that by running [`git config -l`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595848/configuring-git-over-ssh-to-login-once).